# How to access data in localStorage in android app

Tags: javascript, android, html, phonegap

I'm using phonegap to create an Android App. My app is about a simple game where I generate random number to do math. When you answer right, the score goes up and if you lose, you save your name and score at the moment into localStorage. The problem is that I can't view it in android. Can you guys help me?
Below  is the code that I use to view in Browser.

```
function loadPlayer(){
    const lsOutput = document.getElementById("lsOutput");
    var l;
    if (localStorage.length < 5) {
        l = localStorage.length;
    } else {
        l = 5;  
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        const key = localStorage.key(i);
        const value = localStorage.getItem(key);
        lsOutput.innerHTML += `${i+1}- ${key}: ${value}<br/>`;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't attach your code as images but copy it in the body of your question using the code tags

Comment: Set like `localStorage.itemKeyNameHere = 'String Here';`. Get like `console.log(localStorage.itemKeyNameHere);`. Personally, I would get used to using the file plugin. Your data is very limited, otherwise.

Comment: I don't need a  new method to set item into localStorage. Also your way's only get and set specific item. It can't show every item in range. @PHPglue

Comment: Loop over: `for(var i in localStorage){ /* i is key -- localStorage[i] is value */}`

Comment: @PHPglue That's what I have done and it's work on Browser. I want it to work on Android App as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind guys. It's just my old phone can't understand the code. I tried borrow my friend phone and it's work.

Answer (score 1):

localStorage is an object so you can do something like this :

```
var localStorageKeysList = Object.keys(localStorage);
for (var i = 0, max = localStorageKeysList .length; i < max; i++) {
    alert(localStorage[localStorageKeysList[i]]);
}
```

And it's worked on my own android device with a cordova application.

If this don't work for you, you have to use the chrome remote dev tools for inspect manually what's wrong.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/